# Motorcycle failing emissions, high HC

Tags: motorcycle, emissions, triumph

I have a 1999 Triumph Speed Triple T509 885i motorcycle and am located in Austria. I am currently taking it through the yearly inspection which requires an emissions test. The motorcycle is failing the test with a somewhat high HC-level. In Austria the required level for my year of motorcycle is 600 ppm. But the bike was measured at 2142 ppm.

Now I am not a native German speaker and the region of Austria has a very strong dialect. So I mostly have the information from the test results sheet the shop gave me. Here it says that the measurement was made with an engine temp of 60 degrees celsius, which seems kinda low to me. I have read that these tests should be done with a hot engine to get the accurate running results and a cold engine can dramatically alter the results.

What is the opinion here? Was it too cold? I dropped the bike off the day before and therefore couldn't run it hot myself.

IF the numbers are correct, I assume this indicates a rich mixture in the engine. The only thing I can think of is that when I changed the spark plugs after buying it, cylinder 3 showed carbon build up on the plug, but I attributed that to an air-filter that was very dirty on that side of the cylinder. The bike is running fine, no idle issues, all of the headers get warm from a cold start with no revs. No problem with acceleration. I do however, sometimes get a pop in the exhaust on decel. Not on a regular basis, just randomly once per 10 rides or something like that.

Comment: If that engine is water cooled (I think it is) the normal operating temperature should be in the region of 90 celsius. Do you have the option to take it to different test station?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [1997 BMW M3 Failed Smog with High HC](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/94206/1997-bmw-m3-failed-smog-with-high-hc). Both are gasoline powered piston engines, it's the same possibilities.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @weather-vane. The engine is water cooled, yes. I am wondering about that 60 degree temperature though. Seems like an oddly equal number to hit. But the testing systems here in Austria are a little different.

Comment: @gdd, I don't know if it answers my question. But it does provide me with some knowledge that my suspicion might be correct. Another question is, if old fuel would also mess with the numbers? It has been sitting for some months.